# React inline styling not working on elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react, and I can't pinpoint why this inline styling isn't working on my component. My code:

```
  render() {
    const style = {
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      font: 'inherit', 
      border: '1px solid blue',
      padding: '8px',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <UserOutput
         style={style} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is the component js if it helps:

```
import React from 'react';

const UserOutput = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>E plurabis unwhatever</p>
      <p>same thing but different. My name is {props.name}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserOutput;
```

I have all of my imports set up, and the componenets are visible in the DOM, and are accepting protos as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the style prop you pass in, you need to pass it to the element you want to style

```js
const UserOutput = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={props.style}>
      <p>E plurabis unwhatever</p>
      <p>same thing but different. My name is {props.name}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So I am doing this from a course, and styling a button element that was written straight into App.js with inline styling applied directly, in other words not a button component, did work. Is that because the button was not a component, but rather just built directly into App.js? And the way I am trying to style the component, the component has no connection to the styling right now?

Comment: @JoshBangle Correct, inline styles only works with DOM elements, components takes in props and you have to manually map them to what ever you want to do with them

Comment: Thanks a ton, I appreciate your help!